# Calculate Laplace transform of funcion f(x)=1

Tags: functional-analysis, laplace-transform

i have to calculate transforma of Laplace of the function $f(x)=1$.

By definition we have 
$$
L(1)(s)= \displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-sx} dx= \lim_{A \to +\infty} \displaystyle\int_0^A e^{-s x} dx.
$$
I found that $L(1)(s)= \dfrac{1}{s}$ where $Re(s)>0$.

My question is how we find this result? please

Comment: Are you not capable of finding a function for $\int e^{-sx} dx$?

Comment: I'm capable but my question is why the condition $Re(s)>0$?

Answer (score 1):

The laplace transform is defined as

$L\{{f(t)}\}=\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st}\,dt$

Here $f(t) = 1$

$L\{1\} = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}\,dt$

$L\{1\} = \lim_{A\to\infty}\bigg(\frac {-e^{-st}}s\bigg|_0^A\bigg)$

$L\{1\} = \lim_{A\to\infty}\frac{-e^{-At}}s+\frac {e^0}s$

$L\{1\} = \frac 1s$  $\,\,\,\,$ provided  $s\gt 0$

as $\lim_{A\to\infty}e^{-A} = 0$

Comment: But why the condition $Re(s)>0$ to divise of $s$? Please

Comment: $s \gt 0$ is a necessary restriction we make , because the limit of the function diverges for values $\le 0$  Perhaps this [link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LaplaceDefinition.aspx)   will help

Comment: but $s \in \mathbb{C}$. Why the condition $Re(s)>0$? Why not $im(s)>0$?

Comment: If $f(t)$ is a piecewise continuous function defined for t $\ge$ 0 and satisfies the inequality $|f(t)|\le Me^{pt}$ for all t≥0 and for some real constants p and M , then the Laplace transform $L(f(t))$ is well defined for all $Re(s)>p$.

Answer (score 0):

it is a fundamental property of the number $e$ that:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x
$$

from this, and using the elementary formula  for differentiating a function of a function we have:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} e^{f(x)} = f'(x) e^{f(x)}
$$

so if $f(x) = -sx$, we have $f'(x) = -s$, giving:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} e^{-sx} = -s e^{-sx}
$$

which may be written as

$$
e^{-sx} = \frac1{s} \frac{d}{dx} e^{-sx}
$$

this gives:

$$
\int_0^A e^{-sx} \, dx = \int_0^A -\frac1{s} \frac{d}{dx} (e^{-sx}) dx = -\frac1{s} \int_0^A \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-sx}) dx = \bigg[-\frac1{s}e^{-sx} \bigg]_0^A = \frac1{s} ( 1 - e^{-As})
$$

if $A \gt 0$ and $s \gt 0$ then $ 0 \lt e^{-s} \lt 1$ so $e^{-As } = (e^{-s})^A \to 0$ as $A  \to +\infty$

Comment: but $s \in \mathbb{C}$. Why the condition $Re(s)>0$? Why not $im(s)>0$?

Comment: $|e^z| = |e^{x+iy}| = |e^x e^{iy}| = |e^x| |e^{iy}| = |e^x|$ because $|e^{iy}| =|\cos \, y +i \sin \, y| = \cos^2 \, y + \sin^2 \, y = 1$